# Packaging binaries for python scripts on macos so they are added to path

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, packaging

### TL;DR

Outside of specifying `include_package_data=True` and a `manifest.in` file, what are the procedures for including, and invoking binaries in a python package?

### Background

So I have a project that I need to use an included binary from (Chrome WebDriver). Currently I have a `manifest.in` file that looks like this:

```
...
include utilities/webdriver_binaries/chromedriver_win.exe
include utilities/webdriver_binaries/chromedriver_mac
...
```

I am using `Selenium` and want to package the `chromedriver` with the installation. On windows I can just use:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome(f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}{os.sep}webdriver_binaries{os.sep}chromedriver_win.exe")
```

and it works perfectly.

On MacOS however I have tried dozens of approaches including this:

```py
for path in sys.path:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in dirs:
            if "webdriver_binaries" in name and os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(name)):
                browser_path = f"{os.path.abspath(name)}{os.sep}chromedriver_mac"
                print(f"Trying to instantiate browser from {browser_path}")
                browser = webdriver.Chrome(browser_path)
```

`sys.path` seems to have directories called webdriver_binaries (specifically in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.Frameworks/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/webdriver_binaries`) but when I try to `cd` into them they don't exist.